# Show that continuity of probability for increasing sequence of sets implies the same for a decreasing sequence of sets

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, continuity

I have the following definitions of continuity of the probability function:

1. **For an Increasing Sequence of Sets**:Suppose that $B_{1} \subseteq B_{2} \subseteq B_{3} \subseteq \cdots$. Then, $P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}B_{n} \right) = P\left( \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_{i}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}P(B_{n})$.
2. **For a Decreasing Sequence of Sets**: Suppose that $\cdots \subseteq B_{3} \subseteq B_{2} \subseteq B_{1}$. Then, $P\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} B_{n}\right)= P\left( \cap_{i=1}^{\infty}B_{i}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}P(B_{n})$.

I need to show that **1** implies **2**.

Thus far, what I have done is, I have taken the decreasing sequence $$\cdots \subseteq B_{3} \subseteq B_{2} \subseteq B_{1}$$
and since $B_{n}^{c} = \cup_{i=1}^{n-1}B_{i}$ and $B_{n-1}^{c}\subseteq B_{n}^{c}$ (where the $^{c}$ denotes complementation),  I can rewrite this sequence as $B_{1}^{c} \subseteq B_{2}^{c} \subseteq B_{3}^{c} \subseteq \cdots$. Letting $B_{i}^{c} = C_{i}$ $\forall i$, we have that $C_{1} \subseteq C_{2} \subseteq C_{3} \subseteq \cdots$ is an increasing sequence of sets.

So, I can apply **1** to this sequence to obtain $P(\lim_{n \to \infty} C_{n} ) = P\left(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}C_{i} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(C_{n})$.

Then, applying DeMorgan's Laws and the complementation law to the middle part, I obtain $$P\left(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}C_{i} \right) = P\left(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_{i}^{c} \right) = P\left(\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}B_{i} \right)^{c} = 1 - P\left(\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}B_{i} \right) $$

Then, since $P\left( \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}C_{i}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}P(C_{n}$, I have that $1 - P\left( \cap_{i=1}^{\infty}B_{i}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}P(C_{n}) $, or $$ 1 - P\left( \cap_{i=1}^{\infty}B_{i}\right) = 1 - \lim_{n \to \infty}P(B_{n}) $$

**Finally, my question is, how do I turn $\mathbf{P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}C_{n}\right)}$ into $\mathbf{1 - P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}B_{n}\right)}$?**

I know that $P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}C_{n}\right) = P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}B_{n}^{c}\right)$, but I can't figure out how to get any further. Indeed, I certainly don't know what $\lim_{n \to \infty}B_{n}^{c}$ is, and by pulling the $P$ inside the limit, I'd be using exactly what it is I'm trying to prove.

Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: It looks like you are already done, since your last equation proves $$ P[\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i] = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[B_n]$$  and that was the thing you wanted to prove. Note that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} C_n$ is just another way of writing $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} C_n$ when $C_i \subseteq C_{i+1}$ for all $i$ (this is just a definition, nothing to prove here).  Similarly, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} B_i = \cap_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i$ when $B_i \supseteq B_{i+1}$ for all $i$.

Comment: @Michael I'm having trouble with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2453786/proof-of-integral-of-a-simple-measurable-function would it be possible for you to help with that one?

Comment: Blackbird seems to have answerd that well already.

Comment: @Michael what does he mean though by "$(*)$ is the integral of a simple function dominated by$f$"?I thought $f$ was the simple function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A_1, A_2,\dots$ are sets then we can define $\limsup A_n$ and $\liminf A_n$.

$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n$ is only defined if these sets are equal and this with:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=\limsup A_n=\liminf A_n$$

You allready proved that: $$P(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n)=1-P(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n)\tag1$$

If $C_n$ is increasing then $\lim_{n\to\infty} C_n$ is defined and equals $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n$.

If $B_n$ is decreasing then $\lim_{n\to\infty} B_n$ is defined and equals $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$.

So $(1)$ can be rewritten as:$$P(\lim_{n\to\infty}C_n)=1-P(\lim_{n\to\infty}B_n)\tag2$$